# Read a file in extensions Asterisk 13 OpenWRT 17.04? The application ReadFile() is missing in the repository

Tags: file, configuration, chat, asterisk, openwrt

How to read a file in extensions `Asterisk 13` and `OpenWRT 17.04`? For example, I'd like to resend the text from the file to chat. The application `ReadFile()` is missing in the repository, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

ReadFile has been deprecated. According to documentatin you should use the FILE function instead.

FILE function syntax:

```
Set(varname=${FILE(file,0,length)})
```

Instead of Readfile Application:

```
ReadFile(varname=file,[length])
```

Source: [Asterisk Project Documentation](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_ReadFile)

Comment: Yeah, thank you, but I noticed that the `FILE()` function is missing in asterisk `Function FILE not registered`. It seems I should compile it before because of there no any found packages in repositories

Comment: If you will not or can not build the modules it is still possible using AGI. As arheops said  you can call a script that does what you want and return the output to the dialplan.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

1) Use AGI and bash(php, python etc) script to read parts of file you need.

2) Build more modules (see openwrt doc, quite easy).